# Is it spam to insert your own link into an answer to replace a defunct one?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, spam, external-links

I just had the following appear in my review queue.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17370387

I believe I chose the right flag (spam) as the author/group had replaced a link in a question with a link to their own blog.

I wanted to make sure this isn't a regular change they were making. Is there any way to follow up on such a query? Is this something I should have flagged for someone else's attention?

*edit:* I tried the old link and it is no longer valid. Is it still ok to replace it with your own blog link, which the previous owner did not choose to present?

Comment: Well that link being broken is one of the reasons why link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: That link is a different article. No, that's not okay.

Comment: And I've deleted the answer; it was link only anyway.

Comment: Honorable intention, I'd imagine.  The Way Back Machine is still too obscure it seems.  Fixed.

Comment: @HansPassant: Sure, to a blog promoting their services, and nice 'endorsement' from several posts they didn't write (this was not the only edit made). But thanks for looking up the archive link, I fixed all the links now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, that's not okay; the link target is commercial in nature (complete with 'free quote' form at the bottom), while the original was a personal blog. At most it should be replaced with an Internet Archive link instead.

They did so for a series of posts; I've given them a friendly warning.

Comment: Hi, thanks, to answer my question more completely - would there have been a way for me to check that they had done so for a series of posts? And if not, would this have been an ok reason to flag for attention, or too speculative?

Comment: Never mind the above comment. I had only been trying from the review stats - I just realised their profile 'Áctivity' tab lets me check myself, before potentially flagging